# Laravel passport vue components showing as fragments

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I have a fresh install of Laravel passport inside of an existing Laravel 5.3 project of mine.

EDIT: I have now realised that any Vue components (even the default example component) show as fragments if i try and import them.

I am trying to import the Vue components into my application however when I do so, Vue debug tool in chrome is telling me that the elements are fragments.

Looking at the source of the page, it doesn't mention them, so im guessing that the components are being registered into the page correctly

I have been looking around and have found that most places referencing this error in vue are caused by the vue components not being wrapped in a div that roots to an element in the page however the same components have worked in a fresh install.

What should i be looking for to find the problem with this?

Here is my master layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    @include('includes.title')

    <!--Baked in styles -->
    @include('includes.styles')

    <!-- Theme Custom styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    {{--Fonts and icons--}}


    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
    @yield('css')

</head>
<body>
    @include('includes.navbar')
    @yield('content')

    <!-- Scripts -->


    {{--Core ecomplete JS--}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/all.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
    {{--End core ecomplete JS--}}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/sweetalert.min.js') }}"></script>

    @yield('js')

    <!--  Plugins -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/gsdk-checkbox.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-select.js') }}"></script>
    <!--  End Plugins -->

    <!--  GSDK JS -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/get-shit-done.js') }}"></script>





    @include('sweet::alert')
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for my app.js

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

Here is the code for my api.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <passport-clients></passport-clients>
                <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
                <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

I call it from a simple route closure.

Web.php

```
Route::get('api', function(){
    return view('api');
});
```

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Can you show us what you mean by fragments?